# Formula to determine whether a radius is within another radius

Tags: geometry, gps, coordinates, radius

I want to define an operation to computer whether a radius is within another one.
My radiuses are defined by tuples (latitude, longitude, radius), with a radius in meters.
In other words, I want to be able to check whether a circle is within another circle, with an application to GPS coordinates.
I need an algorithm in pseudo-code that could be reused in many cases.

The closest formula I've found is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let circle radii are `R` and `r`.
Calculate distance `d` between circle centers using haversine formula.
Compare `d` with radii:

```
d > R + r:  circles don't intersect
Abs(R-r) <= d <= R + r: circles do intersect
Abs(R-r) > d : one circle lies inside another
```